# Modify sumproduct formula to ignore #value! in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

The formula I want to use is

```
=sumproduct(E3:E24, H3:H24)
```

but the problem is that both columns contain `#VALUE!` errors in various rows.  (In particular: if an error appears in E14, it will appear in all cells across E14:H14.)

How do I modify the formula so that it returns the `SUMPRODUCT` of only the numeric values.

Here's a screenshot of the range I'm working with:

[image]

Comment: or you can use **IFERROR** to fix your source data and then use **SUMPRODUCT** as normal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array version of SUMPRODUCT with IFERROR:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(E3:E24,0),IFERROR(H3:H24,0))
```

Using IFERROR this way requires the formula to be Array Entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

IFERROR should replace the error with a 0:

```
=sumproduct(IFERROR(E3:E24,0),IFERROR(H3:H24,0))
```

Comment: This solution is preferable to avoid having to enter an array formula.